# Python two complement checksum

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, checksum

I am working in script in which I need to calculate the two's complement of certain hex value.

I took this function from stackoverflow:

```
def checksum_calc(s):
    sum = 0
    for c in s:
        sum += ord(c)
    sum = -(sum % 256)
    return '%2X' % (sum & 0xFF)
```

but if I introduced data like:

```
string = '\x00\x03\x03\xFF'
```

is correct but if I introduced it like this:

```
string = b'\x00\x03\x03\xFF'
```

I get incorrect checksum.

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

`bytes` objects already iterate to `int`s, so `ord` doesn't work. Your function will work for `bytes` (but not `str`) by removing the `ord()` call, using `c` directly.